# Piano: Right pinkie and ring finger peculiarly weak

Tags: piano, fingering

I am a right handed person. But my little and ring finger on the right hand are weaker than my left hand. There is a peculiarity about this. The 5-3 configuration (E-G in C major scale) on my right hand is VERY difficult to achieve. On my left hand I can strike 5-3 finger simultaneously quite comfortably with the 4 being up. This I can't do cleanly on my right hand. I have recurring tendonitis problem (both inside and outside) on my right elbow.

Any suggestion how I can deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an alignment and fulcrum problem.  This is something you need to work on with the guidance of a teacher.  I'll include a link to a video but I strongly suggest you work with a teacher.  Too often a student will try something they see and if they do it wrong in the slightest way, it can adversely affect something else.  Since you already have ulnar issues, I would tread lightly.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Will check the video.
I realise that the pproblem is with the 4th finger on the right which just does not lift up much. The left 4th is ok though.

I am not sure if my tutor can fully address this issue. 
I intend to visit my physio to seek her opinion and help too.